# SSRS Report Shows #Error When Converting Number to Currency

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to get the report to show the purchase price which the user enters in a parameter. If the user doesn't enter anything it will say "Undisclosed" otherwise I want it to show the purchase price as currency. I have tried the following:

`=IIF(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value = "", "Undisclosed", Cstr(Format(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value, "C")))`

`=IIF(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value = "", "Undisclosed", Format(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value, "C"))`

`=IIF(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value = "", "Undiscloded", FormatCurrency(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value,0))`

`=IIF(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value = "", "Undiscloded", FormatNumber(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value,0))`

I can get "Undisclosed" to appear but every time I enter a number it shows `#Error`

Comment: what happens if you use this?  =IIF(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value = "", "Undiscloded", Format(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value,"'$'0.00;('$'0.00)"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```
 =IIF(IsNumeric(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value), Format(Val(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value), "C"), "Undisclosed")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this slightly differently. This will avoid SSRS trying to format a non numeric to a currency. `IIF` will evaluate both the true and false outcomes even though only one result can be true for each instance.

I would set the textbox that shows the purchase price up as follow...

Set the `Value` expression to be

```
=VAL(Parameters!PurchasePrice.Value)
```

This will return a zero if the parameter value is left as blank/empty string

Then set the `Format` property of the textbox to

```
$#.00;-$#.00;Undisclosed
```

Assuming you want `$` as the currency symbol. This format string will format the number to two decimals for positive and negative numbers and prefix the $ symbol but for zero values, it will show the work "Undisclosed"